# Minimize Number

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int counter=0;
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    int *arr=new int [num];
    for(int x=0;x<num;x++)
    {
        cin>>arr[x];
    }//[12,12]
        for(int x=0;x<num;x++)
        {
            /*
            first
            ****************************
            12/2=6
            12/2=6
            counter=1
            counter=2
            last value
            counter=2/2=1
            x=0
            second
            ****************************
            6/2=3
            6/2=3
            counter=1+1+1(last value from first operation)3
            ****************************
            another test with input [200,200]
            first case
            200/2=100
            200/2=100
            check=2
            2==2
            then
            startover x=0
            counter=counter/2
            then counter = 1
            -----------
            100/2==50
            100/2=50
            check=2
            2==2
            then startover
            
            */
            if(arr[x]%2==0)
            {
                arr[x]=arr[x]/2;
                ++counter;
            }
                if(counter==num)//true 2==2
                {
                x=0;
                counter=counter/num;//2/2
                }
            if(arr[x]%2!=0)
            break;
        }
        cout<<counter<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Given a number N and an array A of N positive numbers. Print maximum possible operations that can be performed.

The operation is as follows: if all numbers are even then divide each of them by 2 otherwise, you can not perform any more operations.

Input
First line contains a number N (1 ≤ N ≤ 200) number of elements.

Second line contains N numbers (1  ≤  Ai  ≤  109).

Output
Print the maximum possible number of operations that can be performed.

Examples
input
3
8 12 40
output
2
input
4
5 6 8 10
output
0
this is a problem called Minimize Number i write this code but in some test cases i get error for example when input 200 200 i get output 2 when it should be three can some edit the code and tell me why it wrong in thses test cases

Comment: Why do you only divide 2 times?

Comment: You need nested loops. The outer one should stop whenever there is nothing to do in the array. The inner ones: one to check if *all* items are even, another one to divide by 2 *if* all items are even. Count the number of times you divided all items, then exit the outer loop if that number is 0.

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad  why nested loops?  This is not an 0(N*N) problem. First check ALL numbers are even, then if they are, divide all numbers by 2.

Comment: What is the purpose of `counter=counter/num;`?

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad  "if all numbers are even then divide each of them by 2...." Means you must check all and then act conditionally..  Sorry, but I think like an industrial embedded systems engineer.  Missing out on "small" "insignificant" details lin the requirements can sometimes lead to accidents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's start by writing down our algorithm in words:

> 1. Check the current element. At the start, the current element is the first one.
> 2. If the current element is not disivible by 2 (i.e. `x % 2 != 0`), then we stop
> 3. Else we divide it by two
> 4. If there are elements left, we go to the next element and go back to 1)
> 5. Otherwise, we increase our counter, since all elements could be divided by one and we start from the front

The next step is to put this into code.

> Remark: Do not use new int[n]; for a dynamic array. Use std::vector instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements:\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "n: " << n << "\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number:\n";
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
        
    }
    int counter = 0; 
    while( true ) // infinite loop (for 5) )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) // 1) and 4)
        {
            if( numbers[i] % 2 != 0 ) // 2) if we can not divide the number by two, we stop
            {
                goto end_loop; // Rare usecase for goto
            }
            else // 3)
            {
                numbers[i] /= 2; 
            }
        }
        counter++; // also 5)
    }
    end_loop: // jump label for go_to
    std::cout << "Maximum possible iterations: " << counter << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Since Michael has correctly pointed out in the comments, that this code is not strictly following the rules, here's the version, that only divides the numbers IF all numbers are even:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements:\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "n: " << n << "\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number:\n";
        int temp;
        std::cin >> temp;
        numbers.push_back(temp);
        
    }
    int counter = 0; 
    bool all_even = true;
    for(; all_even; counter++ )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < n && all_even; i++ ) 
        {
            all_even &= (numbers[i] % 2) == 0;
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < n && all_even; i++ )
        {
            numbers[i] >>= 2;
        }
        
    }
    std::cout << "Maximum possible iterations: " << counter << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your code as it not take any  just one input and give me nothing as an output

Comment: @golden_hacker You can check the code here, it works: https://onlinegdb.com/FjZ97o44h

Comment: Tthe "rare use-case for `goto`" is actually the usual use-case for `break`.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy except break does not break out of nested loops.

Comment: @infinitezero  Which is probably why the problems states " if all numbers are even then divide each of them by 2 **otherwise, you can not perform any more operations**".  Check first, then divide if possible.  This is a factorization algorithm.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I provided an updated version.

Comment: Actually, `numbers[i] >>= 2;` is a very pointless optimization since most compilers do those kinds of optimizations under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a really *simple* and *efficient* solution then there is one below:

```
#include<iostream>


int main ()
{
    int num { };
    int counter { };

    do
    {
        std::cin >> num;

    } while ( num < 0 ); // checks input to prevent getting a negative number

    if ( num == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << counter << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }

    int* arr = new int [ num ];

    for ( int idx = 0; idx < num; ++idx )
    {
        std::cin >> arr[ idx ];
    }

    for ( bool areAllEven { true }; areAllEven; ++counter )
    {
        for ( int idx = 0; idx < num; ++idx )
        {
            if ( arr[ idx ] % 2 != 0 ) // if not an even number then
            {                          // break the inner loop
                areAllEven = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( areAllEven )
        {
            for ( int idx = 0; idx < num; ++idx )
            {
                arr[ idx ] /= 2;
            }
        }
        else // and here, break the outer loop
        {
            delete[ ] arr;
            arr = nullptr;
            
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << counter << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As can be seen, this solution does not have *bloated and **hard-to-read*** C++ features only to solve a very simple problem. I think that it's fairly beginner-friendly.